# How do I bind data in ascending order to a TableLayoutPanel?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, c#-4.0

My data comes form SQL Server in ascending order, when the data is bound to the `TableLayoutPanel` it will not in alphabetical order. Does anyone have a solution to my problem?

Comment: `TableLayoutPanel` doesn't support data-binding. What control are you using? Also please share some code. Take a look at [MCVE] and [ASK].

Comment: you are right... i am using tablelayoutpanel.controls.add() method to add controls in tablelayoutpanel.

Comment: Why not using `DataGridView`?

Comment: Anyway, when you want to have some help from other developers, usually you need to share some code.

Comment: proReader = PO.getproducts(category_id);
while (proReader.Read()){                productId=Convert.ToInt32(productReader["Pro_id"].ToString());
productName = proReader["name"].ToString();               
colNum++;
btn = new Button();
btn.Name = productId.ToString();     
switch (colNum) {
case 1: pLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(btn, 0, 0); break;
case 2: pLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(btn, 1, 0); break;
case 3: pLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(btn, 2, 0); break;
productsLayoutPanel.RowCount += 1;columnNumber = 0;break;
 }}